# Django REST API serializer.is_valid() always returns false

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a POST request from the frontend to the backend through REST API. I'm passing as data a dictionary which contains all the fields of the table from the database

Data from frontend looks like this:

```
var state = {
  event: {
    name: "test",
    id_organizer: 1,
    start_date: "2019-11-11T11:11:11",
    end_date: "2019-12-11T11:12:11",
    location: "test",
    description: "test",
    id_type: 1,
    status: "pending",
  }
}
```

and POST request like this:

```
axios
      .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addevent", state.event)
      .then(response =>{
        console.log(response.data);
      }) 
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Here is the model of the event:

```
class Event(models.Model):
   name = models.TextField()
   id_organizer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE, db_column='id_organizer')
   start_date = models.DateTimeField()
   end_date = models.DateTimeField()
   location = models.TextField()
   description = models.TextField()
   id_type = models.ForeignKey(EventType, on_delete=CASCADE, db_column='id_type')
   status = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
   class Meta:
      db_table="events"
```

[Here is the database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/958oB.png)

Here is the @api_view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def addevent(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
      data =  JSONParser().parse(request)
      serializer = EventSerializer(data=data)
      if serializer.is_valid():
         serializer.save()
         return Response({'saved':True},status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
      else:
         return Response({'saved':False}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is the serializer:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = '__all__'
```

The request happens but the function serializer.is_valid() always returns false and the response is always {'saved':False}
I already validated the data that it is sent correct and when I printed it, I got the output:

```
{
   "name": "test",
   "id_organizer": 1,
   "start_date": "2019-11-11T11:11:11",
   "end_date": "2019-12-11T11:12:11",
   "location": "test",
   "description": "test",
   "id_type": 1,
   "status": "pending",
 }
```

This data is correct and I got the conclusion that the problem is with the "is_valid()" function.
I've tried to hard-code the data from the api view but it ran into the same issue.
I've already checked and tried most of the posts that exists on this topic and I cannot find my mistake.

Comment: "id_organizer" and "id_type" fields won't take integer directly.  You have to get the instance of models(user and eventtype) and pass the id of those instances to serializer. You can give it a try one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input datetime might not be getting validated with model Datetime field.
You might need to change the date time format using strptime .

Comment: That was the problem, thanks a lot!